# how to upload large size file 30-50 mb file size to server using ftp

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp, file-handling

I am working on a java application that work like a drop box. but when i send a file that have above 5-10mb they don't upload it and show some exception.to upload the file i am using ftp.and set buffer size but its not work properly can you have a idea how to increase the size of buffer and how to upload large size file to server

```
  public void uploadtxtFile(collectinfo myobj,String localFileFullName, String fileName, String hostDir)
            throws Exception {
        //int index = hostDir.lastIndexOf('/');
        //new
        long size = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = start + 10*1000; // 60 seconds * 1000 ms/sec
         FTPClient ftpclient= DBConnection.connect();  
      File file = new File(localFileFullName);
        if (!(file.isDirectory())) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream input = null;
                 BufferedInputStream bis=null;

                try {
                    input = new FileInputStream(new File(localFileFullName));
                    if (input != null) {

                        hostDir = hostDir.replaceAll("//", "/");
                       logger.info("uploading host dir : " + hostDir);
                        boolean bool =false ;

                    //  ftpclient =DBConnection.connect();
                 try{
                    //to set buffer size
                     logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 1111"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());

                             ftpclient.setBufferSize(1048576);

                     while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
                        {
                          // run
                        }
                     ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                     while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
                     {
                           // run
                     }
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 2222"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());

                   if(  ftpclient.isConnected()){                   
                    //  here server timeout error is get
                       logger.error("here server timeout error is get");//new
                       bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 3333"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());

                   }  else{
                       logger.error("here server timeout error is get");//new

                             bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp  not store file 6666"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                       ftpclient= DBConnection.connect();
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is new connection 9999"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                       ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                       bool =  ftpclient.storeFile(hostDir, bis);

                   }
                 }catch(Exception ex){
                     logger.error("the problem into the null pointer "+  ex);
                     BackgroundService.pendingQueue.add(myobj); 
                     } finally{
                       bis.close();
                    input.close();
                   }
                   logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 4444 "+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                        if (bool) {
                            logger.info("Success uploading file on host dir :"+hostDir);
                        } else {

                             logger.error("file  not uploaded.");
                            // BackgroundService.pendingQueue.add(myobj); 
                        }

                    } else {
                         logger.error("uploading file input null.");
             }
                } catch(Exception ex)
                {
                     logger.error("Error in connection ="+ex);
                    BackgroundService.pendingQueue.add(myobj);

                }finally {
                     ftpclient.logout();
                     ftpclient.disconnect();
          }

            } else {
                  logger.info("uploading file is not exists.");
            }
        }
    }
```

and the exception that show is below

```
1.org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught whilecopying.
2.  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

in small file size uploading time is also show that exception but that time the file will upload 
can any one help me to shout out this issue

Comment: This error doesn't appear to be related to buffer size.  It appears that the client is timeout while waiting for the file to be transferred. I suggest you find out why the client is timing out. a 50 MB file is not that big these days.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a simple example? Can you post an exception callstack?

Comment: if it is not a buffer issue so when i upload a file that size is 200 kb they show same error then i am increase the size of buffer so the exception is gone that i think its buffer problem